# nodejs - using electron with ffi

Tags: node.js, electron, ffi

i have nodejs x86 on windows 10 x64 and i installed electron with npm using this `npm i -g electron` and have a .dll file for driving external device.

i am using electron to develop desktop application.

i searched for finding a way for calling dll functions from js and i found ffi package. in first place i installed node x64 but i faced this error

`App threw an error during load
Error: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.`

then i searched it and i found this [issue](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/1075)  on github.

i uninstall my nodejs and replaced it with x86 version and this error still remain on my project. it seems that when i install ffi with npm `npm i ffi`, npm downloads source files and compile it with host architecture(x64) then ffi compile it self with my visual studio 2015 on x64 mode. 
i even try to install ffi with `npm i ffi --arch=ia32` but it did not work.
i donot have dll source files so i cannot rebuild it for any specific architecture.

How can i use electron 32bit version with ffi 32bit?

Is there any way to download ffi prebuild version and attaching it to project?

I want to use any version of electron (x64 and x86) and using my same 32bit dll.

Comment: 64bit can handle 32bit dll. This error happens when you have spaces in the file path. So C:\Program Files\... would throw error. Hope this helps. Other same issues here, https://github.com/node-ffi/node-ffi/issues/258 https://github.com/node-ffi/node-ffi/issues/168 and https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/issues/267

Comment: so you mean i change my nodejs installation path? my project path has no spaces.

Comment: nodejs installation path is fine. But try the path to the .dll with no whitespaces.

Comment: well there is no spaces in my dll path. actually i think problem is something else. i created an another directory (another nodejs package) and initialized it with `npm init` and i just installed only _node-ffi_ and _sleep_. i run `node test.js` and it worked. the simple single node application communicate with my device throw dll file correctly. but now i copied the test.js to my electron app directory and run it with `node test.js` same error comes up. the problem is on `const ffi = require('ffi')` line of code. it cannot import the module properly or electron's node-js has problem with it.

Comment: I know its late but for others , for working with `32bit dll` , install `32 bit NodeJS`,  and for `64bit dll` install `64 bit nodeJS` . After installing ffi , ref ,electron-rebuild modules  do one thing  only run `electron-rebulid  --arch=ia32`  it will build your all native modules again.  (note:- when you set the architecture of the nodeJS comparative to your dll , no need to pass the --arch flag with electron-rebuild )

Answer (score 0):

The error typically happens when trying to load a 64-bit DLL from a 32-bit application.

In most cases, `electron-rebuild` should solve this issue for you, by rebuilding modules for the correct environment.